# Teleport a GameObject to the center of an OpenCVRect object in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opencv, transform

I want to teleport a gameobject to the center of the OpenCVRect object, but I couldn't do the coordinate transformation. I failed after repeated teleportation.

```
private void ResultOpenCVRectToResultSpider(OpenCVRect rect)
{
    float textureWidth = texture.width;
    float textureHeight = texture.height;

    Matrix4x4 transCenterM = Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(-textureWidth / 2, -textureHeight / 2, 0), Quaternion.identity, new Vector3(1, 1, 1));

    Vector3 translation = new Vector3(spiderPrefab.transform.localPosition.x, spiderPrefab.transform.localPosition.y, spiderPrefab.transform.localPosition.z);
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(spiderPrefab.transform.localEulerAngles.x, spiderPrefab.transform.localEulerAngles.y, spiderPrefab.transform.localEulerAngles.z);

    Matrix4x4 trans2Dto3DM = Matrix4x4.TRS(translation, rotation, Vector3.one);

    Vector3 resultPoint = new Vector3(rect.x + rect.width / 2, rect.y + rect.height / 2, 0);

    resultPoint = transCenterM.MultiplyPoint3x4(resultPoint);

    resultPoint = trans2Dto3DM.MultiplyPoint3x4(resultPoint);

    spiderPrefab.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(resultPoint.x, resultPoint.y, zPos);
}
```

When I transform in this way, it unsuccessfully teleports my object to different places. How can I solve this?

(spiderPrefab here is a gameObject. please ignore the name)